# /etc/init/suricata stopping CentOS from booting up

Tags: centos, init.d

I am using CentOS 6.6. I put [this](https://github.com/lruppert/suricata-scripts/blob/master/shell/suricata.init) content into /etc/init.d/suricata.  I also ran

```
sudo chkconfig suricata on
```

to make suricata run at boot.  My problem is that it is now preventing Centos from booting up.  The log ends with three lines all saying

```
sd 2:0:0:0 [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I tried the Centos rescue disk and managed to get into the command line but /etc.init.d was unpopulated.  It appears that it becomes populated later on and the suricata script prevents CentOS from booting up.

Is there a way for me to get rid of /etc/init.d/suricata so CentOS can boot up?   In Debian, one can use ctrl-alt-F4 to get to the command line but that is not working in CentOS. It may depend on the reason for the hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the rescue disk to go into the bash shell.  I then found the suricata executable in /usr/bin/suricata and renamed it /usr/bin/suricata1 so /usr/bin/suricata could not be found at boot.  That enabled me to boot up normally.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not

Turn machine on edit the kernel line in the grub menu and type "single" so when it boots into single user mode.

http://www.uptimemadeeasy.com/linux/boot-centos-into-single-user-mode/

When the machine comes up you should get a command line where you can type

chkconfig suricata off

Then suricata should not run at start up.

Sorry if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: When I type "chkconfig suricata off", I get ""error reading information on service suricata:  No such file or directory".  Thanks,